# Convert LOTTIE to WEBP in Java

Tags: java, webp, lottie

Is there any library to convert LOTTIE animations to WEBP files?

There are several C++ and Python libraries (like [PyLottie](https://github.com/FHPythonUtils/PyLottie)), but I can't find anything for Java.

Comment: Perhaps ask at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).